# Comparing two columns of an output in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, compare, aix

I have a requirement to compare two columns of an output, which are numerals, check if they are equal and proceed to a set of statements if they are equal else print a set of statements in case they are un-equal.

```
# lsvg -l appvg | grep 2rrdbase_lv
2rrdbase_lv         jfs2       8       8       1    open/syncd    /lpar2rrd
```

From the above output, I need to compare the two columns(column 3 with numeral value '8' & column 4 with numeral value '8', check if they are equal and print a set of statements if equal, else if un-equal branch to another set of statements.

Would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: may be good to show what did you try so far

Comment: and add a few more lines of sample input plus the expected output given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton I need to look for a particular filesystem in that output, which is why i have grep'd '2rrdbase_lv', and then the operation proceeds to check for the columns 3 & 4 and check if they are equal.
 If they are equal, branch to a set of statements and if they are not equal, branch to another set of statements.

Comment: That's fine but to get help, read my comment again and just do what I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe:

```
lsvg -l appvg | awk '{if($3==$4){print "Equal "} else {print "Unequal"}}'
```

Or formatted like this if you have lots of statements:

```
lsvg -l appvg | awk '
    $3==$4{
           print "Equal"
           statement1
           statement2
           next                # to avoid processing the "else" statement below
          }

          {
           print "Unequal"
           statement1
           statement2
          }'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that columns 3 and 4 are equal for all lines (rather than executing different commands for each individual line):

```
if lsvg -l appvg | awk 'NR > 2 && $3 != $4 { exit 1 } END {exit 0}'; then
  echo "Columns matched in each line"
else
  echo "Columns were different in some lines"
fi
```